# Gradient background color on ::selection

Tags: css, selection, gradient

Is there is a way to add gradient color to CSS `::selection`?

---

if I use something like this:

```
::selection {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ee4037 0%, #eb297b 100%);
}
```

It does not work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No.

Per [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/::selection)

> Only a small subset of CSS properties can be used in a rule using ::selection in its selector: color, background-color, cursor, outline, text-decoration, text-emphasis-color and text-shadow. Note that, in particular, background-image is ignored, like any other property.